# Contaction of Kronecker Delta with another Kronecker Delta

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-delta

If a space is of dimension $d$, the Wikipedia article seems to suggest that contracting the Kronecker delta with itself gives $2d(d-1)$.

But this seems confusing to me, say that I have $4$ dimensions (ie. four values for the indices to run over), will not $\delta_{\mu}^{\nu} \delta_{\nu}^{\mu}$ be equal to $4$?

Comment: Read carefully. Wiki gave that formula for the generalized Kronecker delta : $$\delta^{\nu_1\nu_2}_{\mu_1\mu_2}\delta^{\mu_1\mu_2}_{\nu_1\nu_2}=2d(d-1)$$